# how to check the two rows based on condition and club into single row in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, if-statement

I have data frame which looks like :

```
Id survey suvery_link Primary_call alternate call
1   form1  link1       7/18/19                   
1   form1  link1                      8/18/19
2   form1  link1       8/18/19                 
2   form1  link1                       9/18/19
3   form1  link1       8/18/19                 
3   form1  link1                       9/18/19
4   form1  link1       7/18/19                 
4   form1  link1                       8/18/19
1   form2  link2       8/18/19                   
1   form2  link2                      9/18/19
2   form2  link2       7/18/19                 
2   form2  link2                       8/18/19
3   form2  link2       7/18/19                 
3   form2  link2                       8/18/19
4   form2  link2       8/18/19                 
4   form2  link2                       9/18/19
```

#### I am trying to get new  data frame as following

```
Id survey suvery_link Primary_call alternate call
1   form1  link1       7/18/19       8/18/19
1   form2  link2       8/18/19       9/18/19             
2   form1  link1       8/18/19       9/18/19
2   form2  link2       7/18/19       8/18/19          
3   form1  link1       8/18/19       9/18/19
3   form2  link2       7/18/19       8/18/19
4   form1  link1       7/18/19       8/18/19
4   form2  link2       8/18/19       9/18/19
```

I used the following code but is not code

```
df.sort_values(['Id','survey',survey_link','Primary_call','alternate call']).drop_duplicate('ID')
```

its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['Id','survey','suvery_link'], as_index=False)[['Primary_call','alternate_call']].max()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good solution:

```
table.groupby(['Id','survey','suvery_link'], as_index=False)[['Primary_call','alternate_call']].max()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend handle date as datetime, and you can use `max()`:

```
df['Primary_call'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Primary_call'])
df['alternate_call'] = pd.to_datetime(df['alternate_call'])

df.groupby('Id', as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: it's not working please the see question once again

Comment: i have the same id which has the details of form 2 when used your code it removes the duplicate Id of form2 too if you see the question again you will understand it